# Split string into several two character strings

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have this string `8S8Q4D1SKCQC2C4S6H4C6DJS2S1C6C`

How can I split this string into substrings that consist of 2 characters per substring? I'm confused because I cannot find a delimiter to split them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    "8S8Q4D1SKCQC2C4S6H4C6DJS2S1C6C".split("(?<=\\G.{2})")
));
```

Comment: Will this not truncate the last character of odd length strings?  Also, using regex for simple problems usually makes the code less readable as it really just adds a second problem. I like to think of the programmers that will maintain the code after me.

Comment: @nybbler Just tested it. It doesn't truncate. The last character still has two characters preceding it. It also works for a single character. This may in fact be a bug =/

Comment: When it does what you want, it's a "feature" not a bug ;)

Comment: @nybbler FYI, I figured it out. The regex _DOES NOT_ work on a single character or the last character of an odd length string. But it already split the point immediately before that character. So it doesn't match and the remaining (1 char) goes into the last bin.

Comment: This does not do what was asked. It just creates 2 sub-strings first with 2 characters and second with the rest.

Comment: @PSIXO Yes it does. Just dropped the above in a public static main along with `import java.util.Arrays` and ran it: `[8S, 8Q, 4D, 1S, KC, QC, 2C, 4S, 6H, 4C, 6D, JS, 2S, 1C, 6C]` which is exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Doesn't work for me:

  `String test = "abcdefghijklmnop";
  String testArray[] = test.split("(?<=\\\\G.{2})");`
Result:
`testArray = {String[1]@4172} 
 0 = "abcdefghijklmnop"`

Comment: Not working for me in Android in only splits the first two and the rest is not splited

Comment: @ThanosFisherman Just tested it again. It works for java se 1.8.0_131. Maybe you should also double check the  number of backslashes you are using, since what you posted doesn't match what's in the answer.

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;public class test {public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(Arrays.toString("abcdefghijklmnop".split("(?<=\\G.{2})")));}}` || `C:\...>javac test.java` || `C:\...>java -cp . test` || Result: `[ab, cd, ef, gh, ij, kl, mn, op]`

Comment: Well it works as expected when I run it from standard java but not when I run it on Android. Very weird. You can try it yourself too. So I ended up using the `substring` answer in Android.

Comment: Had to reverse the string and reverse the groups. I was grouping numbers: 69090923 ->69,090,923. Still if the last group had 3 digits, I end up having empty group at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) of the String class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a split like this on your own.  You could use something like substring in the following way:

```
public String[] customSplit(String src, int size) {
    Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < src.length(); i += size) {
        vec.add(src.substring(i, (i+size > src.length()) ? src.length() : i+size);
    }

    return vec.toArray(); 
}
```

Comment: why not use the actual split function? That's why it's there.

Comment: Well one *possible* reason is that `split` with a gnarly regex *could* be significantly slower.  OTOH @nybbler's code would be faster if (s)he used a `String[]` instead of a `Vector`.  So no +1 for this answer from me.

Comment: @Stephen C - Fair enough.  I'm not used to working with arrays in a language that allows dynamic array sizes

Comment: in Java, arrays are not dynamically sized.  But you don't need a dynamically sized array in this case.  You can calculate the required array size from the length of `src` and the value of `size`.

Comment: @Stephen C: Right, I may have chosen my words poorly. What I meant to say was an array with size determined at runtime. Thanks for reminding me that Java can handle that tho.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a[2].Length; i++)
{
    string ss = (8S8Q4D1SKCQC2C4S6H4C6DJS2S1C6C).Substring(i, 2);
    Console.Write(ss);
    i++; 
}
```