# Split a string after each two characters

Tags: java, string

I want to split a string after each two characters.

For Example:

```
String aString= "abcdef"
```

I want to have after a split `"ab cd ef"`

How can i do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Well, what have you tried, and what happened? Have you looked at the methods available on `String` to find a method which allows you to extract part of a string based on indexes?

Comment: substring can help you ^^

Comment: Look at [Split string into several two character strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788596/split-string-into-several-two-character-strings)

Comment: Thanks you evereydoy for your help, this answer is very easy and it work with what i want to do :

 `String repl = "abcdef".replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0 ");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This **negative looakahead** based regex should work for you:

```
String repl = "abcdef".replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0 ");
```

**PS: This will avoid appending space after last match**, so you get this output:

```
"ab cd ef"
```

instead of:

```
"ab cd ef "
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! your answer ist the best easiest answer :D

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out.

Answer (score 11):

Use regex:

```
        String str= "abcdef";

        String[] array=str.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");

        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Output:**

> `[ab, cd, ef]`

Comment: This is it! But I suggest `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));`  instead of the `for`. Also, put the output in the answer, so people see its effects.

Comment: @acdcjunior:Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Output [ab, cdef] for Android with Java8. Why?

Comment: It is working with Java 8 as well. I tried with www.jdoodle.com and it worked

Answer (score 6):

If you want the output to be the same string with extra spaces, you can simply use:

```
String newString = aString.replaceAll("(..)", "$1 ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String aString= "abcdef";       
int partitionSize=2;
for (int i=0; i<aString.length(); i+=partitionSize)
{
    System.out.println(aString.substring(i, Math.min(aString.length(), i + partitionSize)));
}
```

Comment: This answer would benefit by a small commentary about what's going on and why you did it this way.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    String[] a = "abcdef".split("(?<=\\G..)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a));
```

output

```
[ab, cd, ef]
```

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f7d4f4c542139aee36e0aab03e145fa5.png  What wrong?

Comment: @Leonid Veremchuk: #metoo

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily like here :

```
    String k = "sdfjsdf";
    String s = "";
    for (int i=0;i<k.length();i++){
        s+=k.charAt(i);
        if (i%2 != 0){
            s+=" ";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "teststr";
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    tmp.append(s.charAt(i));
    if (i % 2 == 1) tmp.append(" ");
}

System.out.println(tmp.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<s.length()-2;i+=2){
     sb.append(s.substring(i, i+2));
 if (i!=s.length()-3){
    sb.append(" ");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String st = "abcdefg";
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    int i = 0;
    while(i<st.length())
    {
        int j=i+2;
        if(j>st.length())
            j=st.length();
        array.add(st.substring(i,j));
        i=j;
    }

    System.out.println(array);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

```
    String aString= "abcdef";
    String[] arr=aString.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
```

Comment: Output [ab, cdef] for Android with Java8. Why?