# Fastest way to convert string to string array in Java

Tags: java, android

What is the fastest way to convert string to string array like below(split by 2 char):
String input="127856";
String[] output={"12" , "78" , "56"};
Currently I'm using `for` but very slow:

```
public static String[] mySplit(String input){
    List<String> res=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length()-1; i+=2) {
        res.add("" + input.charAt(i) + "" + input.charAt(i+1));
    }
    String array[]=res.toArray(new String[0]);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Here's a one liner: `String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\G..)");`

Comment: @GBlodgett I doubt a regex would be faster than a loop, though

Comment: In which way do you consider your code to be too slow? What kind of measurements lead to that insight "it's too slow"?

Comment: that is slow (concatenationo of chars ans strings) `"" + input.charAt(i) + "" + input.charAt(i+1)` - try `input.substring(i, i+2)` (also creating a list to create an array is not the fastest.. despite easiest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use regex, you can use `substring`, which should be much quicker than string concatenation:

```java
public static String[] mySplit(String input){
    int len = input.length(), index = 0;

    // Arrays are faster than lists
    String[] array = new String[len/2+len%2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i+=2, index++) {
        array[index]=input.substring(i,i+2);
    }
    // To handle strings with an odd number of characters
    if(input.length()%2==1) {
        array[index]=input.substring(input.length()-1);
    }
    return array;
}
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##jZG9coMwDMd3nkKXu9xBSUjDShn6AJ3SLZfBgAETY1NbJKE5nj0VuOk1nerBH/Jf0k9Sw05s3RTHm2g7bRAaekc9Chk9JV4umbXwxoS63ro@kyIHiwzp2KERqtofoB12nRToOwMI1fUYXD2gJRSC5ApSZ43oXmHtByt6F/xC9ufEm5WbDbwawwYLzHAomUVuAGumQAqLdtb8ZGSTkpwVP9@NFHkTh7Qv40Myq0ttwJ8AxJyGjpeJZb2la5jG3whhGIBjndYceD9/HFKHbPvMzil8sRJhHLjg4x36XQNBFpKDU1k4C6yBuHVRgOrbjOrQJeQ1MyynolwpovQfO7KM03T7f5QH3/X2gcpw7I1yARJv/DO2kxYFtDRP/1c7K0sD2w3U9DbSFLmjH5TKdyOJUDutfx/1gmV5wcuqFs1Rtkp3H8Zifzpfhs9FEBDNON6@AA)

Comment: 5.5x times faster than my function.

Answer (score 1):

The output array of your function should contain half of the input length elements (e.g. `out.length` is `input.length() / 2`). Next, each position in the output starts at the output index multiplied by 2 and ends at one more than that (but `String.substring(int, int)` is *exclusive*). I think the "fastest" way to write your function is something like,

```
public static String[] mySplit(String input) {
    String[] out = new String[(1 + input.length()) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        out[i] = input.substring(i * 2, Math.min(2 + (i * 2), input.length()));
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: this function 5x faster than my function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex for it:

```
public static String[] mySplit(String input){

  String[] output = input.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
  return output;
}
```

The regex `(?<=\G...)` matches an empty string that has the **last match** (`\G`) followed by **three characters** (`...`) **before** it (`(?<= )`).

However, The Time complexity would be the same.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993729/split-a-string-after-each-two-characters

Comment: Not working! if input="1122334455", this return just {"11","22334455"}

Comment: Not Possible! Please have a look at this: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/r7mzbqqCpI

Answer (score 0):

It is often the best solution to use the standard libraries. `java.lang.String` provides a method `String[] split(String regex)`. In a regex, a . stands for a single char, you want 2 chars, so the regex is `..`

```
public static String[] mySplit(String input){
   String array[]=input.split("..");
   return array;
}
```

As it is untested, i cannot tell you what happens if the numbers of chars in the string is odd.

Edit: As it happens with untested code, the regex is wrong. Please disregard my answer.

Comment: `jshell> "abcd".split("..")`
`$1 ==> String[0] {  }`

Comment: Return empty string!!!