# Split string every n characters

Tags: string, split, kotlin

What would be an idiomatic way to split a string into strings of 2 characters each?

Examples:

```
"" -> [""]
"ab" -> ["ab"]
"abcd" -> ["ab", "cd"]
```

We can assume that the string has a length which is a multiple of 2.

I could use a regex like in [this Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788718/829571) but I was hoping to find a better way (i.e. using one of kotlin's additional methods).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Once Kotlin 1.2 is released, you can use the `chunked` function that is added to `kotlin-stdlib` by the [KEEP-11](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/window-sliding.md) proposal. Example:

```
val chunked = myString.chunked(2)
```

You can already try this with [Kotlin 1.2 M2 pre-release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-2-m2-is-out/).

---

Until then, you can implement the same with this code:

```
fun String.chunked(size: Int): List<String> {
    val nChunks = length / size
    return (0 until nChunks).map { substring(it * size, (it + 1) * size) }
}
```

```
println("abcdef".chunked(2)) // [ab, cd, ef]
```

This implementation drops the remainder that is less than `size` elements. You can modify it do add the remainder to the result as well.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the implementation, if case the original string length is not even.

Comment: @LiorBar-On Why? It will just drop the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

A functional version of `chunked` using [generateSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html):

```
fun String.split(n: Int) = Pair(this.drop(n), this.take(n))
fun String.chunked(n: Int): Sequence<String> =
        generateSequence(this.split(n), {
            when {
                it.first.isEmpty() -> null
                else -> it.first.split(n)
            }
        })
                .map(Pair<*, String>::second)
```

**Output**:

```
"".chunked(2) => []
"ab".chunked(2) => [ab]
"abcd".chunked(2) => [ab, cd]
"abc".chunked(2) => [ab, c]
```