# Change a list to map in Kotlin while customize this convert

Tags: java, functional-programming, kotlin

```
var listOfNums = listOf(1,9,8,25,5,44,7,95,9,10)
var mapOfNums = listOfNums.map { it to it+1 }.toMap()
println(mapOfNums)
```

result

```
{1=2, 9=10, 8=9, 25=26, 5=6, 44=45, 7=8, 95=96, 10=11}
```

while I need this result, it adds contents of next element to the current element while I need to map current element to next element

my goal result

```
{1=9, 8=25, 5=44, 7=59, 9=10}
```

Comment: This will be much easier with the windowing and chunking features coming in 1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Kotlin 1.1:

First, use zip to create a list with adjacent pairs. Then you drop every other pair, before converting it to a `Map`. Like this:

```
val list = listOf(1,9,8,25,5,44,7,95,9,10)
val mapOfNums = list.zip(list.drop(1))
                    .filterIndexed { index, pair -> index % 2 == 0 }
                    .toMap())
```

For Kotlin 1.2:

Kotlin 1.2 brings the `chunked` function which will make this a bit easier. This function divides the list up in sublists of the given length. You can then do this:

```
val list = listOf(1,9,8,25,5,44,7,95,9,10)
val mapOfNums = list.chunked(2).associate { (a, b) -> a to b }
```

Comment: Also: `list.chunked(2).associate { (a, b) -> a to b }`

Comment: @voddan Ah, nice. Fixed.

Comment: I showed an implementation of `chunked` using 1.1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665151/839733)

Answer (score 1):

We can step over every second index and map listOfNums[it] to listOfNums[it+1]

```
val listOfNums = listOf(1,9,8,25,5,44,7,95,9,10)
val mapOfNums = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
(listOfNums.indices step 2).forEach {
    mapOfNums[listOfNums[it]] = listOfNums[it + 1]
}
println(mapOfNums)
```

EDIT: 
Another better solution suggested by ephemient:

```
 (1..listOfNums.lastIndex step 2).associate { listOfNums[it - 1] to listOfNums[it] }
```

Elegant!

Comment: This answer assumes the precondition of listOfNums having an even size.

Comment: `(1..listOfNums.lastIndex step 2).associate { listOfNums[it - 1] to listOfNums[it] }` avoids the mutable map and drops a trailing odd element.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

```
import io.reactivex.Observable

...

val listOfNums = listOf(1,9,8,25,5,44,7,95,9,10)
val mapOfNums = Observable.fromIterable(listOfNums)
        .buffer(2)
        .map { it[0] to it[1] }
        .collect(
                { mutableMapOf<Int, Int>() },
                { map: MutableMap<Int, Int>, (first, second) -> map.put(first, second) }
        )
        .blockingGet()
println(mapOfNums)
// {1=9, 8=25, 5=44, 7=95, 9=10}
```