# Android Studio Kotlin regex different than expected

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, kotlin

I'm having a problem with a specific regex that is returning a different value than expected when running in Android Studio.

**Scenario:**

The code is simple:

```
val regex = "(?<=N|E|\\G)\\d{2}(?=\\d*$)".toRegex()
print("${regex.findAll("N2032354345").count()}")
```

This should print 5 as there are 5 matches in this string (https://regex101.com/r/6PDbkI/1) and if we run in on [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/1YCCnK) or in [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/r1QlMyXaX), the result is the expected 5.

However, in Android Studio, the result is 1:
[image]

**Theory:**

It seems that the regex in Android Studio is failing to use the `\G` operator (which might be related to [Kotlin split with regex work not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52072404/3410697))

Anyone faced the same problem? Is there any way to change the regex to a similar one that isn't failing in Android Studio? Am I missing some setting?

Comment: Sounds more like a bug to me, considering it works fine in the playground

Comment: That's what I thought @Zoe. Do you happen to know what is the best place to report such issue?

Comment: And that's correct @WiktorStribiżew. But I'm developing for Android Studio, which is not returning 5, but 1 instead (which is NOK)

Comment: I think you may use a workaround like `"(?<=[NE]\\d{0,100})\\d{2}(?=\\d*$)"` (you may adjust the 100 value).

Comment: I can confirm that that workarround works @WiktorStribiżew. But it seems to be an ugly one :/

Comment: @PedroOliveira probably the [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). Maybe [the JetBrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) **if** this isn't limited to Android Studio, but also affects IntelliJ

Comment: It is working in IntelliJ so it seems to be only Android Studio related. Thank your for your links.

Comment: There is nothing ugly about it, it is compliant with the Android/Java regex engines that support constrained width lookbehinds. Besides, judging by your pattern, you do not expect too many digits in the input string.

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew. Indeed, I'm not expecting more than a dozen of digit pairs. And I wasn't aware of that support in Java regex. I take that "ugly" back then :)

Comment: Current Google issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119296826

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Android `Pattern` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern) lists `\G` as a supported operator:

> `\G`    The end of the previous match

Hence, it sounds like an Android Studio bug.

Until it is fixed, you may use a work around for your scenario that involves just a dozen digits in the input:

```
val regex = "(?<=[NE]\\d{0,100})\\d{2}(?=\\d*$)".toRegex()
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=[NE]\d{0,100})` - a position that is immediately preceded with `N` or `E` and 0 to 100 digits
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?=\d*$)` - that are followed with 0 or more digits to the end of the string.

Comment: Thx @WiktorStribiżew  +1 for saving my day